# Running several scripts in parallel bash scripts on remote machines

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, ps, thredds

in the following bash script , we want to run in parallel several scripts on remote machines

```
ssh $server_a  /tmp/activate_nodes.bash &
ssh $server_b  /tmp/activate_services.bash &
ssh $server_c  /tmp/activate_components.bash &
ssh $server_d  /tmp/activate_nfs.bash &
.
.
.
```

not sure about to put the "`&`" on the end of the script or some other approach ?

**Note** the target is to run all 25 scripts on 25 diff machines , so all runing of the scripts will be in few second , while scripts proccess on remote machine will still run until end

Comment: Seems a fair enough approach to me - what is your concern? If you put a `wait` at the end of the script it will wait for all the background tasks to end before terminating the script - otherwise the background tasks might get terminated.

Comment: my concern is that this steps are simple , and maybe I missed something

Comment: oh...lol... then its just simple : )  ... remember the wait at the end though - it will be useful : )

Comment: *"The target is to run all 25 scripts on 25 diff machines"*... do you mean you want to start 625 processes altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running these in parallel is fine, except for the interleaved output.  To save output for later analysis, you can also "tee" the logs for later inspection:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ssh $server_a  /tmp/activate_nodes.bash      2>&1 | tee ${server_a}_$$.log &
ssh $server_b  /tmp/activate_services.bash   2>&1 | tee ${server_b}_$$.log &
ssh $server_c  /tmp/activate_components.bash 2>&1 | tee ${server_c}_$$.log &
ssh $server_d  /tmp/activate_nfs.bash        2>&1 | tee ${server_d}_$$.log &
wait
```

Comment: I would add `2>&1` before the pipe to catch the error messages too.

Comment: Thanks Jetchisel!  You should feel free to edit answers (treating SO as a WIKI).  Edits are reviewed as well.